# w command : meaning of ":0" and ":0:0" in FROM field

Tags: linux, command-line

What do ":0" and ":0:0" mean in the FROM field ? I'm curious.

```
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT

oddjob   tty7     :0               18:18   10:03m  3:36   0.07s gdm-session-worker [pam/gdm3]

oddjob   tty1                      21:45   18:17  47.25s  0.00s xinit /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc -- /etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc :1 -auth /tmp/serverauth.g2M3EzPqao

oddjob   pts/0    :0               20:00    1.00s  0.45s  0.00s script

oddjob   pts/1    :0.0             21:05   58:46   0.04s  0.04s /bin/bash
```

Comment: This question should be on unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

`:0` is the first X connection, and `:0.0` is the first screen of the first X connection.

Comment: what do you mean by the first screen ? For example I have chromium running but it doesn't appear as a screen. Sorry if it's a stupid question

Comment: @PerrierCitror: An X server can be configured to have multiple screens, each running on a different physical or logical video card and arranged adjacent to one another in any arbitrary manner. They are numbered starting from 0.

Comment: So why don't I have a ":1"  for tty1 ? As you can see in the WHAT field I typed startx just for academic purpose, so there should be another connection, no ?

Comment: Because :1 isn't running on tty1.